# Cross-domain AJAX calls during development: possible?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajax, angularjs, cross-domain

I am developing applications using Angular and the client side is 100% JS. I am about to replace an old application made using ExtJS but I will not change the server-side. Only the client-side be re-coded from scratch.

I would like to work on this project from anywhere and any machine but I need to be able to perform cross-domain AJAX queries with the original server (server-side is ASP.NET MVC with IIS and I don't want to install Windows + everything on all the computers I use). Is there a way to do this easily?

Thanks for your ideas!

PS: JsonP is not a solution for me.

Comment: Look at [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/WD-cors-20090317/) support.. like http://jsfiddle.net/ricardohbin/E3YEt/ for the dev environment http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

Comment: You are right Quentin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

1. At the end of the day you have to enable CORS in your server.
2. You can use a CORS proxy https://github.com/gr2m/CORS-Proxy for development. This proxy will actually change the request header of X-Origin which browsers even can but "won't" because of policy. So you will be able to make Cross Origin Requests.

Answer (score 1):

If neither JSONP nor CORS are availble to you as options then you will have to take help of server side scripting.

You can create a method in your server side code and get the response from desired cross domain url and return the response to your javascript function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)

Comment: So I need to use Access-Control-Allow-Origin and therefore to modify the server's responses, right? There is no way I can do this from the client-side, by playing with Google Chrome options for example?

Comment: have  you  tried  starting  chrome  with  the --disable-web-security  flag?  it's been a while  since I've used that, but it may still work